# How do I change labels on y scale of a scatterplot using characters?

Tags: r, ggplot2

An example of my data is:

```
df <- data.frame(Percent.diff=c(6.3,7.78,12.22,4.81,5.93,8.89),
                 modal.response=c(1,2,3,1,1,1.5), 
                 Gr=c("R","G","B"), 
                 Sub=c("Plant","Animal","Water"))
```

I have a scatterplot with a continuous variable (Percent.diff) on the x axis. Although the y axis is numeric (modal.response on a survey question), it relates to categories of responses (ie 0-"The same", 1-"Slightly worse", 2-"Moderately worse",3-"Significantly worse", but there are also responses options in between, eg 1.5). I have made other bar charts with the same data but for this chart specifically I want to make a scatterplot. My only issue is that I want to change the labels of the points on my y axis, so that instead of it simply showing 0-3, I want it to show 0-"The same", 1-"Slightly worse", 2-"Moderately worse",3-"Significantly worse". I have tried making the variable into a factor, but this doesn't work because I think it needs to be a continuous scale and I get the error message "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

This is the code I'm using for my plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Percent.diff, y=modal.response, color=Sub)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Gr, fill=Sub), size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 8, 21:25))
```

Thank you

Comment: have you tried the `labels` argument in `scale_y_continuous`?

Comment: I have just tried this using scale_y_continuous (labels=c("0-The same","1-Slightly worse","2-moderately worse","3-significantly worse")), but that didn't work, I got this error "Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths", I think because of the values in between (eg 1.5). I added "1.5" to the labels but then the problem is this replaces the existing scale and my plot now shows values at the bottom of the scale (on "0-The same"). These should actually be plotted at "1-Slightly worse".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `scale_y_continuous`, making sure breaks and labels have exactly the same length.

If you want to keep 0, then you also have to adjust limits, otherwise it's cropped by default.

This should achieve what you're looking for:

```r
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(Percent.diff=c(6.3,7.78,12.22,4.81,5.93,8.89),
                 modal.response=c(1,2,3,1,1,1.5), 
                 Gr=c("R","G","B"), 
                 Sub=c("Plant","Animal","Water"))


ggplot(df, aes(x=Percent.diff, y=modal.response, color=Sub)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Gr, fill=Sub), size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3, 8, 21:25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0:3),
                     labels=c("0-The same","1-Slightly worse","2-moderately worse","3-significantly worse"),
                     limits = c(0,3))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that works. Do you know how to wrap the label names? eg so that "significantly worse" runs across two rows rather than on one long row?

Comment: Use `\n` where you want the carriage return to be. For example `"3-significantly\nworse"` would put worse on a second line.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much